# Wordnik api. Allow request from only one domain

Tags: wordnik

I am using wordnik api from client side. And, as a protection of api key, i want to only allow my website(domain) to send request with that api key. For example, in Firebase, we can control which ip addresses or domains can send requests with that key. Is this possible in wordnik api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, we don't offer a way to limit access by domain or IP. We encourage you to call Wordnik from the server side so that your key is not made public in the client.